# swift 5 - recursive closure func

Tags: ios, swift, recursion

So i am trying to recurs my own func :

```
func finishConfigSession() {
    if let config =  self.handler?.configurationSession?.config {
       config.finishSession()
    }
}

func logOut(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.sdk.cancelCurrentRunningControlFlow()
        self.finishConfigSession()
        self.sdk.logoutAsynchronously(handler: { (result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                self.finishConfigSession()
                // call again to logout
                failure()
            } else {
                success()
            }
        })
}
```

When i am getting an error i want to call logout func again in order to complete the func with success.
Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: `self.logout(success: success, failure: failure)` then? Might need a `weak self`.

Comment: @Larme Oh man.... i tried this: self.logout(success: success(), failure: failure())
such  a stupid mistake.
thanks! and you can put it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the answer :

```
func finishConfigSession() {
if let config =  self.handler?.configurationSession?.config {
   config.finishSession()
 }
}

    func logOut(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.sdk.cancelCurrentRunningControlFlow()
        self.finishConfigSession()
        self.sdk.logoutAsynchronously(handler: { [weak self] (result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                self?.logOut(success: success, failure: failure)
                failure()
            } else {
                success()
            }
        })
}
```

Thanks to @Larme who helped